# ThreeTen Backport causing runtime only on some devices

Tags: android, threetenbp

Does this trace look familiar to anyone?  It's only happening on a handful of devices.  ThreeTenBP is a dependency in a dependency.

```
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider: Provider org.threeten.bp.zone.TzdbZoneRulesProvider not found
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:233)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:183)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:373)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:416)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:494)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesInitializer$ServiceLoaderZoneRulesInitializer.initializeProviders(ZoneRulesInitializer.java:123)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesInitializer.initialize(ZoneRulesInitializer.java:89)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.<clinit>(ZoneRulesProvider.java:82)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.zone.ZoneRulesProvider.getRules(Unknown Source:0)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.ZoneRegion.ofId(ZoneRegion.java:143)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:358)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.of(ZoneId.java:286)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.systemDefault(ZoneId.java:245)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.Clock.systemDefaultZone(Clock.java:137)
10:16:33 E AndroidRuntime : at org.threeten.bp.LocalDate.now(LocalDate.java:165)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added proguard rule:

```
-keep class org.threeten.bp.zone.*
```

Seems to have fixed it!

Comment: Thanks, proguard rule missing :(